# Is there something wrong with this question that is preventing answers?

Tags: discussion, tags, participation

[I posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106983/c-sharp-invoke-remote-delete-of-directory), and I have no response. No comments, no answers, and 24 views.

I am not exactly an old hand here, but I have never seen a question go this cold. Is there more I should have done do get attention?

Comment: Perhaps it's because people simply don't know a good answer.

Comment: @SteveP. The thought crossed my mind... But generally even those get at least a +1 for a good question.

Comment: If people don't know enough about what you're asking, it may be difficult for them to determine that it deserves a +1.

Comment: You left no hint at all *why* it is slow in your specific case.  It requires somebody to guess at an answer without any way to know that it could be helpful.  At least post a snippet, describe what you did to research the problem yourself and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been 12 hours. Wait a little longer.

People have had to wait quite some time for answers. There is a [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge just for not having activity in a week! It has been awarded over 273,000 times! Give it some time, and you might gain an answer. Consider adding code. The more detail that you give on your questions, the easier it will be to help you. We can't know exactly what your problem is unless we see code. The question you are asking is also not incredibly clear, so that could be a contributing factor as well

Comment: Sweet, a tumbleweed badge :D. As for code, the only code I could post is for solutions I don't want / need at present. Thanks though.

Comment: What do you mean? You could post the utility's code

Comment: The question is really: "Are there any .NET classes that can invoke the remote machine to complete the deletion of the directory instead of relying on the calling machine?" I *could* post the code as I iterate through AD, and find the old profiles and include a simple Directory.Delete(UNCPath) but does that not really just obfuscate the core question?

Comment: Good luck getting a Tumbleweed badge having it linked on Meta now...

Comment: @CodyGuldner: I've seen far worse questions than this one.  Implied in the question is the phrase, "If so, what are they and how are they used?"  You should understand this, if you've been on Stack Overflow for any length of time.

Comment: But we also are not supposed to ask for recommendations, best practices, or products... so its really a balancing act, is it not? And, honestly if someone knew of a managed library for .NET or a code set of APIs the answer would certainly not be yes, but "Look at _______". Although I am open to a good way to open the question up.

Comment: It's not a recommendation question.  The number of possible solutions is probably quite small, and they are all tightly bound to programming issues.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so you would agree with "Give it more time" and the question is not inherently flawed as it stands now?

Comment: I think the question is fine.  If it doesn't receive any attention in the next two days, you can put a bounty on it.